# Converts rows in columns in vertica based on key

Tags: sql, vertica

I have table in vertica as detailed below:

```
key value   rank
ABC 3.6138  1
ABC 1.8845  2
ABC 0.604   3
ABC -0.0351 4
ABC -0.2873 5
```

I want convert all the values of column- value into column separated by comma as details below:

```
Key value
ABC 3.6138, 1.8845, 0.604, -0.0351, -0.2873
```

A quick help would helpful for me a lot. Thanks in advance

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of stuff for path

```
SELECT key, 
       ConcatValue = STUFF(
             (
              SELECT ',' + value FROM TableName ORDER BY Rank 
              FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '' 

             ) 
FROM #TableName GROUP BY key
```